# Pack kusudama flowers bouquet for shipping

Tags: paper

What is the best way to pack paper flowers for shipping?

I was thinking to use packing peanuts and some newspaper but I'm not sure if this will work and my bouquet will arrive without bents or big damage.

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: Voting to leave open even though it does not fit a strict interpretation of the rules. It does have to do with an aspect of craft that is not likely to find a home anywhere else. After all, many of us are making arts and crafts to sell/send to others. So if someone has had decent results with their packing methods that is useful info to the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone wonders how I end up to manage this, the "solution" was much simpler than I thought. I have just put the bouquet into the box and I have used a lot of tissue paper to fill any gaps and also on the top.
I have sent over 10 parcels now and every one arrived perfect :D

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: You can select your own answer as the preferred one.

Answer (score 5):

You can use wire to make the bouquet stay in the middle of the shipping box without touching the sides by attaching the firm part of the bouquet to the sides of the box with it, then adding newspaper, etc. (again to the base), to make sure it doesn't move, just in case.

[image: shipping]

Comment: Good suggestion -- and great diagram! Welcome :)